# sendmail smtp configuration - Relaying denied

Tags: smtp, sendmail, docker

**Agenda:** Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39913757/5528059) , here **container1** forward smtp request to **container4**(10.1.2.2) for sending mail.

Install **sendmail** (`apt-get install sendmail`) in ubuntu after that adding below line in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`, I can able to send mail using telnet command.

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `gworks.mobi')dnl
```

### sendmail listen port 25

[image: easy for your reference]

php varaible passing like

```
$smtpHost= '10.1.2.2';//your smtp host  ';
$smtpConf = ['port' => '25'];
```

but it throws error like

> `<mail@gworks.mobi>` ... Relaying denied

before that I can directly pass isp provider of my mail

```
    $smtpHost= 'xxxxx.bluehost.com';//your smtp host  ';
    $smtpConf = [
        'auth' => 'login',//auth type
        'tsl' => 'tsl',
        'port' => '26',
        'username' => 'xxxxxx@gworks.mobi',//smtm user name
        'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'//smtppassword
    ];
```

can anyone explain how to send mail using **sendmail** for the above scenario?

Comment: Is 10.1.2.2 the local address of the container that the sendmail is running in ?

Comment: yes you right @drookie

Comment: And whet the `sendmail -bv mail@gworks.mobi` tells ? Plus, what does `/etc/mail/local-host-names` contain. Or wherever the `local-host-names` for this container is.

Comment: thanks @drookie I solved relaying issue by just add `connect:10.1.2.4  RELAY` in `/etc/mail/access` . here 10.1.2.4 is my remote host ip.

Comment: now I have an issue in authentication. if you can, please help http://serverfault.com/q/808345/366250