# In telnet command can't authenticate sendmail in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, sendmail

I have install sendmail in ubuntu and try to authenticate using telnet command. please see my stuff

generate **username** and **password**

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("username");'

perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("password");'
```

**Test with telnet command**

```
root@cthree:~# telnet 10.1.2.3 25
Trying 10.1.2.3...
Connected to 10.1.2.3.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 cthree.gworks.mobi ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Tue, 11 Oct 2016 12:29:35 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: cthree.gworks.mobi(OK)-cthree.gworks.mobi [10.1.2.3]
ehlo 10.1.2.3
250-cthree.gworks.mobi Hello cthree.gworks.mobi [10.1.2.3], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
YkVzZWFiLm6vYmk=
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
d5VuY29lCTHyMw==
535 5.7.0 authentication failed
```

It does not login, it shows **authentication failed error**, I am 100% sure username and password is right.

**/etc/mail/sendmail.mc**

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `gworks.mobi')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo', `hash /etc/mail/auth/client-info')dnl
```

**/etc/mail/auth/client-info**

```
AuthInfo:gworks.mobi "U:mail@gworks.yyy" "I:mail@gworks.yyy" "P:xxxxxxxxx"
```

I little doubt about **username** and **password** generation, can anyone mention what is wrong here? why it is not get authenticate.

Comment: You are probably setting the auth with the cyrus-sasl2 library, so, assuming you did everything right (I would check that again) - let's start with the question *"Where is the password stored and why do you think it's okay"*.

Comment: password stored in `client-info` file "P:password". I can able to login to my email account using the same password and username in browser. you can check client-info file in my question. I am not set any configuration related to cyrus-sasl2. is this problem?